# Graduate School in Computer Vision

Tags: optimization, image-processing, computer-vision, career-development

I intend to apply to graduate school in the near future (I am a few years out of undergrad), and I want to apply to math departments with researchers that study image processing and computer vision.  I have been looking at researchers in various departments and seem to have identified one approach to one problem in the subject: the optimization of the "energy" of active contours for segmentation.  Identifying this has helped me look up mathematicians who do not explicitly state that they work with image processing on their webpages and instead list optimization as their interests.Are there any other general mathematical approaches to the various problems of computer vision that I
should be aware of that could help me find research groups that align with my interests?